# The 'Pragma' header should not be used, it is deprecated and is a request header only

Tags: javascript, php

How to fix this?

The 'Pragma' header should not be used, it is deprecated and is a request header only.

It increases in my console tab warning

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

DirectoryIndex dashboard.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Options -Indexes 

ErrorDocument 400 /notfound

ErrorDocument 401 /notfound

ErrorDocument 403 /notfound

ErrorDocument 404 /notfound

ErrorDocument 500 /notfound

ErrorDocument 502 /notfound
```

Comment: Looks like a htacces or serveur configuration problem more than a PHP/Javascript problem. Can we see your .htacces ? Or the header you're creating in php if so ?

Comment: Edited just now for the htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding basic Cache control on your htaccess :

```
# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|css|gz)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
 </FilesMatch>
 <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
 </FilesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
</filesMatch>
# Disable caching for scripts and other dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
```

Pragma is the "old way" for passing cache information, it will be overwrited by Cache-control header and should remove the error.

Comment: Thanks! Im kind of experimenting right now. Is it safe if I just put a header_remove( 'Pragma' );. in my php file? Thank you again!

Comment: Btw, what does '\.' after file match means? Does it means search all directories?

Comment: Lastly, there is a blue warning increasing in my console, About performance and security, if your okay with it, will edit the question for you to see the picture

Comment: Hello? Can you please answer my last 2 questions?

Comment: There is no safety problem with Pragma don't worry, it's just deprecied, you can remove the line with header_remove if you want.

Comment: \. juste catch the "." in file extention like ".ico", that's a small regex, catching files type to apply header

Comment: I understand, last question, so basically, this will be applicable to all of my directories? THANK YOU! <3

Comment: Or should I put different directories in the htaccess file?

Comment: Also, should this fix the warning in my code like 'Response should include 'x-content-type-options' header.' ?